# why can't resolve the required file Laravel on on my hosting server?

Tags: laravel, server, hosting

I'm trying to connect the folder public with Laravel but I can't

API is in another folder called Laravel01

I've changed the url on index.php

```
require __DIR__.'/../laravel01/vendor/autoload.php';
```

but I can't step back to the root folder

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/homepages/15/d831964969/htdocs/api/../laravel01/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php7.4') in /homepages/15/d831964969/htdocs/api/index.php on line 24
```

it keeps on api folder when it must link with laravel01 folder

sorry for my English and I hope everybody can understand me, thanks a lot

Comment: "_another folder called Laravel01_" Is it `Laravel01` or `laravel01`?

Comment: Try `require __DIR__.'/homepages/15/d831964969/htdocs/api/vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: laravel01, autocorrection sorry

Comment: it don's work like that Muhaddis...

Comment: ```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/homepages/15/d831964969/htdocs/api/homepages/15/d831964969/htdocs/laravel01/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php7.4') in /homepages/15/d831964969/htdocs/api/index.php on line 24

Comment: Scratch that `__DIR__` and try only `require '/homepages/15/d831964969/htdocs/laravel01/vendor/autoload.php';`, use the full path to the file

Comment: it works kerbh0lz... thank you